# How to specify the signature hash algorithms I will accept?

Tags: openssl

Using openSSL API, on a TLS client, I specified a unique cipher suite with `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()`. When I use wireshark to look at the messages, I see in the Client Hello message, the cipher suites allowed are the ones I specified.

But if I look at the Extension: signature algorithms, I see that the client seems to accept a large number of algos, including some that don't seem very secure to me, like MD5.

How can I change this behavior?

Note: I posted this question first on Information Security Stack Exchange, but it was moved to the Super User website, I don't know why. This question is really relevant about programming. I am asking about the openssl API, not the commandline tools.

Comment: *"How to specify the signature hash algorithms I will accept?"* - Do you mean in the server certificate or the bulk data transfer? If the latter, what is the string you are using for `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`? You can clear most of the weak/wounded cipher suites with `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("HIGH:!ADH:!RC4:!MD5");`. You can see what OpenSSL will use with `openssl ciphers 'HIGH:!ADH:!RC4:!MD5'`.